# iOS Job ad for Synechron shows 404 error

Tags: bug, ios-app

The following link shows 404.

https://clc.stackoverflow.com/jobs/131564/server-side-web-development-in-java-synechron?an=4_xUs3Phb8MrHtwMDMGhnA4MQMAIIr4yJlTwMch7cjExMDQwMzCwMzAfsDt9ztJxwRU7Bs6tb7p-bSgrW-kBAA&cr=229376&ct=0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fjobs%2F131564%2Fserver-side-web-development-in-java-synechron&sig=qJErm0-VsrTBLw
[image: job ad for synechrin]

When I click the job ad, it shows "Not Found"

[image: Not found error]

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: I see. This is duplicate.